# can not get MAP to work within system.config packages for SystemJS

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

Hello I have the following config set up for systemJS:

```
    System.config({
    packages: {
        //sets the root path of the Angular2 App
        'DesktopModules/RegentDMS/app': {
            //module format expected in application, register = System.register or System.registerDynamic compatibility module format
            format: 'register',
            //default file extension for paths
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            map: {'./app' : './DesktopModules/RegentDMS/app'}
        },
    } 
  }); 
System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

The default extension works fine but I get is a 404 error in the console that says:

> GET http://localhost:81/app/boot 404 (Not Found)

But if I change it to the following:

```
    System.config({
    packages: {
        //sets the root path of the Angular2 App
        'DesktopModules/RegentDMS/app': {
            //module format expected in application, register = System.register or System.registerDynamic compatibility module format
            format: 'register',
            //default file extension for paths
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
    } 
  }); 
System.import('/DesktopModules/RegentDMS/app/boot.js')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Then it does work.

QUESTION:

how can I set up the MAP setting so that I can use the short hand app/ to refer to the absolute path of DesktopModules/RegentDMS/app in import statements like app/boot (meaning DesktopModules/RegentDMS/app/boot.js)

Thanks

## EDIT #1:

So i changed the ./app to app as suggested and tried both of the following:

```
 map: { 'app': './DesktopModules/RegentDMS/app' }
 map: { app: './DesktopModules/RegentDMS/app' }
```

and this does not work when using any of the following import statements:

```
System.import('app/boot')
 System.import('./app/boot')
```

I get the following error for both:

> http://localhost:81/app/boot 404 (Not Found)

### SOLUTION:

Move the map declaration to the config object like so:

```
    System.config({
    packages: {
        //sets the root path of the Angular2 App
        'DesktopModules/RegentDMS/app': {
            //module format expected in application, register = System.register or System.registerDynamic compatibility module format
            format: 'register',
            //default file extension for paths
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    },
    map: { 'app': './DesktopModules/RegentDMS/app' }
  }); 
System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Comment: does not work, edited answer for more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Langley suggested in comment, you should use `app`, not `./app` (name not path), and move `map` definitions from `packages` object to the `config` object.

> The map option ... allows you to map a module alias to a location or package:

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#map

Comment: Try to put map on `config` object, not on `config.packages`

Comment: that worked, moving the original map declaration to the config object and not the packages object got it to work.  Ill accept your answer, can you edit it so that your comment is included in the answer

Comment: Map was inside packages, not inside config itself or me!!!!  Thank you so much, what a help.